# magento2 addtocart not working in chrome and extremely slow

Tags: magento2, addtocart

I have magento2 installed on local machine the addto cart works in mozilla on product page how ever its extremely slow and on chrome it shows adding after addto cart but it does not add at all, there is no error in console but it does not add to cart.

Comment: maybe do you use localhost as domain name?

Answer (score 4):

You have to change your domainname **localhost** to **127.0.0.1**.

Its basically create problem in magento 2.

you have to change your already existing domain name from **`core_config_data`** table with path value is `web/unsecure/base_url` and 
**`web/secure/base_url`** to `http://127.0.0.1/magento2/`.

Remove **`var`** folder from root and run upgrade command.

Thanks.